# Useful transitional phrases for scientific writing

Tags: phrases, synonyms, writing

I am writing a scientific paper at the moment and need a hint for some formulations...

I already got some sentences/phrases for my paragraphs:

- At first our approach was...
- Due to the performance issues...
- In addition to that...
- Additionally...
- In our cases...
- Those optimizations, which are essential...
- For calculating this problem...
- Furthermore a problem was...
- Besides there is the another solution of...

Could you supply some more synonyms or other ideas for starting a paragraph?

Would something like *Next I want to point out...* be correct?

Comment: These look okay to me. Moreover, don't forget [_moreover](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+moreover&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)._

Comment: 7th point: you don't _calculate a problem_.

Comment: For solving this problem? Or dealing with?

Comment: @ascenator: yes, you can solve a problem, but you can calculate a specific quantity, e.g. the position of a particle at time 0 or the voltage across a resistor. I wouldn't use _to deal_ in the context of a scientific problem, though.

Comment: The one that begins with "Besides" is odd and also contains an extra "the."  Perhaps "Besides this, there is another solution of..."  Your best bet is to read papers in your field and try to find phrases you like as transitions.  See how people who have done what you're doing did what you're hoping to do.  (<-- That's a lot of "do" for one sentence...)

Comment: A few questions for you, OP. Is your scientific paper academic or meant for general consumption? Depending on which of these two you're writing you will have several different style considerations that will come into play. This is important because it will render several of your existing introductory clauses unusable and possibly suggest others.

Comment: You should definitely avoid the singular first person in a scientific paper, so I would not use "Next I want to point out". You can use the plural first person ("We should next point out...") if it works for your purpose, though.

Comment: [Besides/Moreover] there is another solution:    {on next line, start describing your solution.}

Comment: 2nd point - you would only say "due to _the_ performance issues" if you have already discussed them and are now dealing with the consequences of those issues. If you are introducing the subject, skip the "the".

Comment: 3rd point - Ordinarily, you can skip "to that", and just say "In addition,"

Comment: 5th point - "In our cases" is normally used if you are dealing with multiple instances of a phenomenon, and usually in a medical context. If you are establishing the reason that you have chosen a particular experimental approach, you would say, "In our case".

Comment: 8th point - Ordinarily you should insert a comma after "furthermore".

Comment: DON'T use transitional phrases unless you really know you have to. In scientific writing, keep it simple and brief and don't use superfluous words. If you don't know, leave it out. It will sound better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ascenator, the examples you listed are fine, except (and as Mark Thompson pointed out) you would not use the first-person singular pronoun. However I would add that there are many more single-word transitions (originally, finally, preliminary, randomly,etc.) that you could use before you have to resort to using multi-word and phrasal transitions.

You are only practically limited by: the writing type (expository); the intended audience (because if you are writing for a general audience it wouldn't be a "scientific paper"); and preceding paragraph from which you are transitioning.

As a former Physics major in high school and college, and having written many technical papers to report on laboratory research results, I always recommend reading actual research papers. This will give you specific examples from the target context for which you are writing.

I hope this helps.